# Programmatically inserting checkboxes in Excel

Tags: c#, excel, checkbox, docx

I have a question about manipulating Excel environment within C#. I am a beginner programmer and I never programmed in a different environment than C#, therefore, I'd kindly request to avoid VBA hints.

My program has a function that reads out the table of contents of a .docx document, converts it to plain text, and copies it into a RichTextBox, so the user can see an example. This is how it looks like.

[After you click the "Into Excel" button, it gets copied to Excel,](http://puu.sh/6lDbC.png).
However, this is not what I entirely want. I'd like it to look [like this](http://puu.sh/6lDgo.png). What it currently does, is pretty much the same, except it has no checkboxes at all. Just copied text into Excel.

Is there anyway to "foreach" Excel checkboxes after every line?
So far, I tried inserting "☐" symbol after each line. It works, but it's not clickable.
This is my code, if it'll help in any way.

```
        #region Checklist
    private void btOpenDocx_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            tbFile.Text = openFileDialog.FileName;
            rtbText.Clear();
        }    

        DocxToText dtt = new DocxToText(tbFile.Text);
        string txt = "";
        try
        {
            txt = dtt.ExtractText();
            txt = Regex.Replace(txt, @"\t", " ");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,
                "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Application.StartupPath + "\\sandwich.txt", true))
        {             
            writer.WriteLine(txt);
            File.SetAttributes(Application.StartupPath + "\\sandwich.txt", FileAttributes.Hidden);
        }

        List<string> textLines = new List<string>();
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(Application.StartupPath + "\\sandwich.txt");

        bool read = false;
        int enter = 0;

        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            if (line == "Inhoud")
            {
                read = true;
                enter = 0;
            }
            else if (line == "")
            {
                if (enter != 2)
                {
                    enter++;
                }
                else
                {
                    read = false;
                }
            }

            if (read)
            {
                if (line != "")
                {
                    if (line == "Inhoud")
                    {
                        enter = 0;
                        rtbText.AppendText(line + "\r\n");
                        textLines.Add(line);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        enter = 0;
                        rtbText.AppendText(line + "   \r\n");
                        textLines.Add(line);
                    }
                }
            }

            File.Delete(Application.StartupPath + "\\sandwich.txt");
        }
    }

    private void btExtract_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (rtbText.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Nothing to copy.");
        }
        else
        {
            //Extracted text gets copied into Excel
            Clipboard.SetText(rtbText.Text);

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlexcel;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;

            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            xlexcel = new Excel.Application();
            xlexcel.Visible = true;

            //Add a new a workbook
            xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Add(misValue);

            //Set Sheet 1 as the sheet you want to work with
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            //Set your range
            Excel.Range CR = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1];

            CR.Select();

            xlWorkSheet.Paste(CR, false);
        }
    }
    private void btReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tbFile.Clear();
        rtbText.Clear();
    }

    #endregion
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up, I should have read the rules. I'm very nervous since it's my very first time asking a question publicly.

Comment: You might like to take the tour from the help menu in the top bar.